# Extbase TYPO3 adding Custom JS Library to Backend Module

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I want to use custom JS libraries in my extbase extension. Is it possible to use add_additional footer data api in a backend module controller?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a viewhelper in your backend Fluid template:

```
<f:be.container
  addJsFile = "{f:uri.resource(path:'js/script.js')}">
  <!-- Content -->
</f:be.container>
```

**UPDATE:**

As mentioned by @biesior (thanks!) the method `addJsFile` is deprecated. Here is an example using the new and recommended be.container viewhelper method `includeJsFiles` instead. This new function can include multiple JS files instead of just one:

```
<f:be.container
 includeJsFiles = "{0:'{f:uri.resource(path: \'js/script1.js\')}', 1:'{f:uri.resource(path: \'js/script2.js\')}'}" >
  <!-- Content -->
</f:be.container>
```

See the corresponding [Fluid viewhelper documentation](https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_fluid_1_1_view_helpers_1_1_be_1_1_container_view_helper.html).

Comment: Nice tip, one note from PHPdoc of VH: `$addJsFile Custom JavaScript file to be loaded (deprecated, use $includeJsFiles)`

Comment: according to the documentation the correct syntax for the array should be `includeJsFiles = "{0:'{f:uri.resource(path: \'js/script1.js\')}', 1:'{f:uri.resource(path: \'js/script2.js\')}'}"`  or am I wrong?